# Where should I specify [[gnu::transparent_union]]?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Clang supports using the [C++11 generalized attribute syntax for vendor-specific attributes](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#non-standard-c-11-attributes). This means that in theory, I can use any attribute that Clang supports, and tag it with the `[[attribute]]` syntax.

However, I'm having issues using the `transparent_union` attribute. I remember that C++ lets you put attributes basically anywhere, so I tried all of the following, to no avail:

```
[[gnu::transparent_union]] union x { int foo; };
// error: an attribute list cannot appear here

union [[gnu::transparent_union]] x { int foo; };
// warning: transparent_union attribute can only be applied to a union definition;
// attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]

union x [[gnu::transparent_union]] { int foo; };
// error: an attribute list cannot appear here
// warning: transparent_union attribute can only be applied to a union definition;
// attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]

union x { int foo; } [[gnu::transparent_union]];
// error: an attribute list cannot appear here
// warning: transparent_union attribute can only be applied to a union definition;
// attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]
```

The correct place to use the `__attribute__` syntax seems to be at the end of the union definition:

```
union x { int foo; } __attribute__((transparent_union));
// OK
```

Where is the right place, if any, to place `[[gnu::transparent_union]]` with Clang?

Comment: Seems, that `transparent_union` is C-only attribute and just ignored in C++ context.

Answer (score 2):

In the C++11 standard, it shows in the grammar that an *attribute-specifier-seq* goes after the *class-key*, which is what `union` is.

```
class-head:
       class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt class-head-name class-virt-specifieropt base-clauseopt
       class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt base-clauseopt

[..]

class-key:
       class
       struct
       union
```

This is confirmed as:

```
union [[gnu::transparent_union]] x { int foo; };
```

seems to be the only syntax that doesn't elicit a diagnostic. So perhaps it's a Clang bug.

Keep in mind that `__attribute__` appears to be a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) while `[[attribute]]` is part of C++.